# Error Code: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: json, list, datetime, indices, strptime

I have the following code for converting datetime in a json file to the desired format (%Y-%m-%d), but it gave me the error code of " list indices must be integers or slices, not str", highlighting the tweet["created_at"] part.

```
counts = {}

for tweet in tweet_list:
    date = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(tweet["created_at"],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
    if date not in counts:
        counts[date] = dict(sentiments=list(), tweet_count = 0) 
    counts[date]["tweet_count"] += 1
    full_text = cleanTxt(tweet["text"])
    counts[date]["sentiments"].append(find_sentiment(text))
```

The tweet_list looks like this, I suspect when I converted the dataframe into json using orient='records', it kind of messed up the formatting?

[image]

To work around this, I tired using orient = 'index' but the final json file will include the row number and can't get ride of it.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I want the output to be in the format of %Y-%m-%d, but the list seems to be a list